# How far can I go back with Facebook Insight API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I have been trying to get historical data for Facebook pages. I was wondering how to determine how far back I can go.

So I know I can go one month back. Is this a rolling window? I also would like to know how far I can go back and not get an api exception like follows.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported operation",
      "type": "FacebookApiException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Is it possible to get all the historical insight data for a given fan page that I have access to.

Thanks and any suggestions that might help with understanding how to do this cleanly and robustly are also welcome.

Comment: Does paginating through the statistics not go back quite far?

Comment: @Igy well I want to be able to say start at this date and then paginate forward

Answer (score 1):

Start with 30 days ending on the current day, e.g.

`/278905338821044/insights/page_fans/lifetime?since=30 days ago&until=now`

The response will have the last 30 days' data, and you can iteratively go through the 'previous' links in the `paging` structure at the end to go back into the past

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "278905338821044/insights/page_fans/lifetime", 
      "name": "page_fans", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1432, 
          "end_time": "2012-09-19T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
         //snip
        {
          "value": 1438, 
          "end_time": "2012-10-16T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Total Likes", 
      "description": "Lifetime The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/278905338821044/insights/page_fans/lifetime?since=1345405748&until=1347997748", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/278905338821044/insights/page_fans/lifetime?since=1350589748&until=1353181748"
  }
}
```

Comment: Igy, I love you ! I've been searching for this answer for days !

Comment: Do you know when the Insights will be fixed? Since the last data is from the 14th of Mai